# Trying to build openface docker container

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile, face-recognition

I am using docker running El Capitan.

I'm new to using docker, and I'm having a bit of an issue building an openface docker container. (Openface is an open source face rec program if you aren't familiar).

I have all of the proper repositories and directories with respect to the instructions on https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/setup/

*Building a Docker Container
This builds a Docker container from a locally checked out copy of OpenFace, which will take about 2 hours on a modern machine. Be sure you have checked out the git submodules. Run the following commands from the openface directory.*

I have in fact checked out all of the submodules.

```
XXXX-MacBook-Pro:~ XXXX$ cd /openface
XXXX-MacBook-Pro:openface XXXX$ docker build -t openface .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 260.6 MB
Error response from daemon: No image was generated. Is your Dockerfile  empty?
XXXX-MacBook-Pro:openface XXXX$
```

The dockerfile doesn't **appear** to be empty.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Here is the docker file:
    http://jmp.sh/17vxhSe

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile

Comment: OK, I've added a link to the file.

Comment: It should be a small text file: "A Dockerfile is a text document that contains all the commands you would normally execute manually in order to build a Docker image. By calling docker build from your terminal, you can have Docker build your image step by step, executing the instructions successively."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20MB Dockerfile? I dont mean the image. [What is a Dockerfile?](https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_four/)